# MongoId rails3, get inner array elements

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I have 2 Models, Kid and friend_list. To the the kid I use:

```
k = Kid.where(email: "adfadf@adfadsfa.com").first
```

Then, to get the friend list I type:

```
k.friend_list
```

and I get:

```
[#<FriendList _id: 5305cb6485216d2689004785, _type: nil, name: "Friends", members: ["5374a1f320db90054c0000ea", "537c63ea20db9040d2000332"], kid_id: BSON::ObjectId('5305cb6285216d2689004742'), teacher_id: nil>]
```

But I only need the "members".

I tried

k.friend_list.members, but I get

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `members' for
#<Array:0x007fcf4b013138> from /Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@blabloo/gems/mongoid-2.8.1/lib/mongoid/criteria.rb:387:in
`method_missing'
```

How can I get only the members array??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Friend_list returns a list of objects, do you want members of each element in a collection or just the members of first element?

Comment: Why are you getting array as result? does `Kid` has `belongs_to: friend_list` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that  `friend_list` returns an `Array` of `FriendList`.

You can create a new list composed of the values of the `members` getter using [`map`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#method-i-map):

```
k.friend_list.map(&:members)
# => [["5374a1f320db90054c0000ea", "537c63ea20db9040d2000332"]]
```

Or, alternatively, if you only meant to have a single `FriendList` per `Kid`, you should change your model to a single `FriendList` object.

For the current model, you can also do:

```
k.friend_list.first.members
# => ["5374a1f320db90054c0000ea", "537c63ea20db9040d2000332"]
```

Comment: Thanks Uri, this solve my problem, Stackoverflow say that I have to wait 12 minutes to accept this answer.